# Favorite Questions and Answers from third quarter of 2016

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2016 through September 30 2016 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2016/07/01)

**As always (as in one time before) I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also good.

Comment: Seriously? two people downvoted *this question* which has been asked every quarter for like three years?

Answer (score 9):

### Questions

- [Has JKR addressed the issue of 'Love Potions' equating to date-rape drugs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139355/51379)

  Given the apparent inconsistencies in the books, I had often wondered what Rowling’s opinion was.
- [In Tolkien's opinion, does Tom Bombadil (and the concept of pacifism) actually hold any power?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140769/in-tolkiens-opinion-does-tom-bombadil-and-the-concept-of-pacifism-actually-h)

  This is that rare question that (a) requires a good deal of analysis, (b) is not primarily opinion-based, and, most notably (c) attracts enough interest to produce numerous high-quality answers. Definitely a cut above the rest.
- [What is the name of the move that Obi-wan uses to remove Anakin's limbs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/140658/51379)

  This is a question that at first looks a little silly. Upon thinking a bit more about *Star Wars*, you realize that *of course* they had to have a name for every single thing in the movie, and it becomes kind of brilliant.
- [Why doesn't Hogwarts have more teachers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/140348/51379)

  Let’s face it, I had never though of this. It should have been  obvious from how few teachers they had, but it takes a special attention to detail to notice the many more subtle ways in which Hogwarts differs from a regular boarding school.
- [What is Darth Vader holding on the cover of the original Star Wars novelization?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138953/51379)

  This is just funny. I would never have guessed what the cover art was going for.

### Answers:

- [Identify movie about very advanced genetic engineering](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139345/51379)

  60 upvotes for a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) answer. Definitely worth noting. I guess *Gattaca* is one of those movies whose name is always on the tip of everyone’s tongue.
- [Marvel comics with robot aliens and major superhero deaths](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141571/51379)

  I didn’t think this could possibly get an answer, because the description was fairly broad, let alone a good one. Plus, it was Marvel Comics, famous for having a million contradictory storylines over several decades. Thaddeus and his encyclopedia knowledge of comics proved me wrong, though.
- [How did Jon Arryn actually find out about “the strong seed”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139747/how-did-jon-arryn-actually-find-out-about-the-strong-seed/139748#139748)

  Another really good answer from Aegon. I would just have assumed it was something everyone knew.
- [What is the significance of the titles of the Shadowhunters series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141396/51379)

  I was wondering whether there was some meaning behind the weird names and titles of Cassandra Clare’s various series. Apparently there was a lot more there than I had imagined!
- [Has an injured Flash ever used super-speed to walk on his hands?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/137660/51379)

  It’s always nice when an unusual question unexpectedly turns out to have a clear canonical answer.

Comment: Upvotes on story-identification questions do not reflect the quality of the answer or the difficulty of finding it; they reflect the popularity of the author or work. (I got 69 upvotes for identifying ["The Last Question" by Isaac Asimov](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49743/let-there-be-light-story-identification).) Evidently this Gattaca movie has a lot of fans. (Is it any good?).

Comment: @user14111 - I could probably have identified it, but I only ever saw about 5 minutes of it. So I don’t really know.

Comment: @user14111 - Yes, it's an excellent film. The whole "the future is the 1930s" noir pastiche is very well executed, the writing is tight and the acting is very good. They leave a lot to the imagination which is always nice and there's pretty much no CGI to distract from the story.

Answer (score 6):

### Questions in underappreciated tags

Part of my pledge to this site for a long time has been to try to popularise some relatively obscure tags (not necessarily obscure *works* of SF/F, but those which haven't had many questions asked about them here on SE). As part of this, I'd like to promote a few tags which don't have many questions but have had some good ones this quarter. Most of them are fantasy novels, because hey, that's my thing.

- [animorphs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animorphs) Special nod to **Fiksdal** for helping to breathe life into this tag. Among his many good questions about this series, I chose the following one which hasn't yet been answered:

  [When receiving thought-speak, does one know who else it's addressed to?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139545/when-receiving-thought-speak-does-one-know-who-else-its-addressed-to)
- [the-princess-bride](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-princess-bride) I'm very pleased with my own success in this tag this quarter, with many great answers from **Radhil**, but here I chose a question which Radhil and I weren't involved with:

  [Why did Humperdinck want to start a war?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139366/why-did-humperdinck-want-to-start-a-war)
- [bartimaeus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bartimaeus) Nod to **Bellerephon** and **Adamant** for helping to breathe life into this tag.

  [What is the ranking order of resilience?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134464/what-is-the-ranking-order-of-resilience)
- [witcher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/witcher) This had a few questions this quarter, and I chose the most significant one:

  [How does Geralt of Rivia meet Yennefer of Vengerberg?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138095/how-does-geralt-of-rivia-meet-yennefer-of-vengerberg)
- [redwall](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redwall) Only one question in this tag this quarter:

  [Suggested order for the Redwall series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134470/suggested-order-for-the-redwall-series)
- [jonathan-strange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jonathan-strange) I enjoyed answering this one:

  [Who is the dark man in the feather suit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139840/who-is-the-dark-man-in-the-feather-suit)

### Answers which redeemed questions

Sometimes a question is posted which is very poorly received initially but gains more traction and upvotes after being redeemed by a great answer.

- [Why does the chandelier unscrew the other way?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133884/why-does-the-chandelier-unscrew-the-other-way) seems like a ridiculous question at first glance, but **DVK-in-exile** provided a canon answer which made the question look more reasonable.
- [Are there toilets on the Hogwarts express?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140343/are-there-toilets-on-the-hogwarts-express) initially received downvotes and even close votes, before **Au101** provided a nice canon answer.
- [What would happen if Romulus Thread killed the District 12 victors?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135535/what-would-happen-if-romulus-thread-killed-the-district-12-victors) was initially closed as primarily opinion-based, but then it was reopened after my answer proved without doubt that the question could be objectively answered.

### Apologies to anyone I forgot!

I always hate answering these "favourite questions and answers" posts, because I know that I'll never be able to remember all the posts I particularly liked. Doubtless as soon as this goes live on the blog, I'll remember more tags I should have mentioned, or more mediocre questions saved by great answers, or just some posts I really really liked which have slipped my mind for the moment.

However, perfectionism must at times be put aside for the sake of practicality. Yes, I'm sure there are things I've forgotten; but it's better to have an imperfect list than no list at all. Thank you for reading.

Comment: DVK's answer on the chandelier question annoyed me a little. Supposition versus research.

Comment: @Valorum In general I prefer answers which are based on a thorough knowledge of the canon, together with some logical reasoning and deductions, to those based on nothing but a quote from an interview or novel. The latter only requires Google-fu, but the former requires expert knowledge.

Comment: I actually rather thought that DVK's answer was a classic case of finding a complex answer when an overlooked one would suit. He's not wrong, it's just not the simplest explanation.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - an expert on Chaos. That's certainly myself :)

Comment: @DVK "Chaos is not a pit. Chaos is a ladder" ... oh, wait, donkey.

Comment: You forgot me, but that's ok, apology accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

### Questions

I rather liked Nathaniel's

- **[Why doesn't the Discworld run out of water?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135286/why-doesnt-discworld-run-out-of-water)**

and RedCaio's

- **[Why are there barcode readers on the bridge of the Enterprise?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135932/why-are-there-barcode-readers-on-the-bridge-of-the-enterprise)**

### Answers

Tooting my own trumpet, I thought my answer to this one went above and beyond the call of duty

- **[Why does Watney’s notebook in The Martian have four holes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/137300/20774)**

And I also rather liked my answer to this one (on the basis that there's [no kill like overkill](https://giphy.com/gifs/overkill-136kOut0qvFB28)).

- **[Was the T-Rex the same one?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133825/was-the-t-rex-the-same-one)**

Comment: There is no reason to down-vote this response. Instead spend your time suggesting questions and answers that you enjoyed on the site this quarter.

Comment: @Adamant - What can I say? I answer the ones I like. If I don't like them, I don't answer them.

Comment: People need to realize that self promotion is perfectly acceptable for my quarterly round-up. And this is atypical of Valorum, because he has certainly commended other people's questions/answers which he had nothing to do with in the past.